# Coerce list from sapply to data frame produces columns of lists instead of int in R

Tags: r, dplyr, sapply, tibble

I am trying to coerce/convert the `list` which returns from `sapply` into a `dplyr::data_frame`:

```
data_df = tbl_df(data_frame(id=round(runif(10,1,5)),
                            Height=rnorm(10,65,10),
                            Weight=rnorm(10,100,25),
                            Strength=runif(10,1,10),
                            Age=rnorm(10,50,15)))

data2_df = tbl_df(data_frame(id=round(runif(40,1,5)),
                            Age=rnorm(40,50,15)))

FUN <- function(data_temp){
  BMI = data_temp$Weight / ((data_temp$Height^2) * 703)
  SBMI = BMI / data_temp$Strength
  id = data_temp$id
  data_older_friends = data2_df[data2_df$id == id & data2_df$Age > data_temp$Age,]
  nOFRIENDS = 0
  avgOFRIEND_AGE = NA
  if (nrow(data_older_friends)>0){
    nOFRIENDS = nrow(data_older_friends)
    avgOFRIEND_AGE = mean(data_older_friends$Age)
  }
  return_df=tbl_df(data_frame(id=id,BMI=BMI,SBMI=SBMI,nOFRIENDS=nOFRIENDS,avgOFRIEND_AGE=avgOFRIEND_AGE))
  return(return_df)
}

sapply_output = (sapply(1:nrow(data_df), function(x) FUN(data_df[x,])))

tbl_df(t(sapply_output))
```

The output is:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
         id       BMI      SBMI  nOFRIENDS avgOFRIEND_AGE
     <list>    <list>    <list>     <list>         <list>
1 <int [1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>  <int [1]>      <dbl [1]>
2 <int [1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>  <int [1]>      <dbl [1]>
3 <int [1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>  <int [1]>      <dbl [1]>
4 <int [1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>  <int [1]>      <dbl [1]>
5 <int [1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>  <int [1]>      <dbl [1]>
```

The output for `FUN(data_df)` is (note inaccurate calculations in last 2 columns):

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
      id          BMI         SBMI nOFRIENDS avgOFRIEND_AGE
   <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>     <int>          <dbl>
 1     2 2.045586e-05 3.462166e-06         5       56.34759
 2     2 2.388499e-05 8.266183e-06         5       56.34759
 3     3 4.001101e-05 4.119298e-06         5       56.34759
 4     1 4.526758e-05 9.436741e-06         5       56.34759
 5     3 2.242063e-05 3.415824e-06         5       56.34759
 6     2 4.252556e-05 4.651436e-06         5       56.34759
 7     5 1.728240e-05 5.536207e-06         5       56.34759
 8     4 4.298384e-05 1.093979e-05         5       56.34759
 9     5 3.532514e-05 5.688031e-06         5       56.34759
10     3 2.001582e-05 2.673569e-06         5       56.34759
```

But, I would prefer a traditional data_frame with columns full of dbl, not columns which are full of lists of dbl

I have tried `tibble::as_tibble` and `as.matrix` and various other combinations, but no luck. Also, I am not looking for a `join` solution, since my actual problem involves 2 very large tables (here I've presented a toy version of the problem) and the result of the "grouping" on table 2 requires specifications from the row in data 1 (thus a row-wise solution seems in order)

UPDATE:  `%>% unnest` can do the trick

Comment: Don't use `sapply` - just `FUN(data_df)` will do it I think.

Comment: The reason I need to use `sapply` is that I need the function to be row-wise. I've updated the original code to reflect that

Comment: R uses vectorised operations - `data_temp$Weight / data_temp$Height` will divide `Weight` for each row by the corresponding `Height` in the same row. There is no need to loop it explicitly.

Comment: `FUN(data_df)` returns inaccurate column calculations for `nFRIENDS` and `avgFRIEND_AGE`

Comment: I don't see how it is the wrong calculation. Your code is `Weight / (Height^2 * 703)` - that will be a very small value most of the time, just like your results.

Comment: You are essentially working with relational data for your bigger problem. This should be approached with calculations on `data2_df` by `id` group, which are then merged back on to `data_df` - Trying to do it all in one step is messy, as you are finding out.

Comment: I guess I should post something closer to my actual problem, but in essence the `data2_df` by `id` group calculation would DEPEND on a variable in the `data_df` row (thus there's no way to summarize the `id` group in a meaningful way without knowing a value from the `data_df` row), which is why I went the `sapply` route to begin with

Comment: Okay, that makes it a little more difficult. It is still essentially a relational/join problem, using a non-equi join `a.id = b.id & b.Age > a.Age` - you could do this using SQL (maybe the `sqldf` package) or the `data.table` package, which supports non-equi joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
res <- map_df(seq_len(nrow(data_df)), ~FUN(data_df[.x,])) 
identical(res, tbl_df(t(sapply_output)) %>% 
                                       unnest)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @b_g  You can use `map_df` to return a dataframe and there is no need for `bind_rows`.   I forgot about that earlier

Comment: Thanks -- and for those reading through this, `%>% unnest` seems to do the trick as well